# Dividing a solid angle into equal parts

Tags: geometry, solid-angle

In 2D, using polar coordinates, I have divided a unit circle into n equal parts (of equal $\theta$) and been able to form equations for the radius arc between the $\theta$ boundaries of the m'th element (m ranges from 0 to 2$\pi$ when m=n). This was easy as there was only one variable to partition i.e. $\theta$ divided into n angles of 2$\pi\div\ n$. I was also able to find the polar coordinates of the mid-point of the m'th equal arc.

Now the point in my doing this was to learn patterns to extrapolate this to a 3D equivalent, and to use 3D polar coordinates to divide a solid angle up equally into n equal parts - of size $4\pi\div\ n$

My question relates to this. One could use the $\delta\Omega =\sin\theta\delta\theta\delta\Phi$ integral to integrate over partitioned coordinates. One could assume a reference start point ($\theta=0,\Phi=0$ on Y-axis etc). But it is self evident in 2D that partitioning that $\theta$ can be equally split and the parts represent equal symmetric elements and their midpoints would be as far away from each other as possible. Now in 3D, partitioning by $\theta,\Phi$ doesn't guarantee that each surface element would have the same surface area, and the centre of each surface area would be as far away from each other as possible. I am looking for a way to generate equations in 3D polar coordinates of the m'th element of the whole solid angle split into n elements. This will come in the form of $\theta$ and $\Phi$ boundaries for each element. Just dividing both angles equally doesn't mean equal surface areas, nor are equal surface areas necessarily not produced by differentially dividing each angle, I.e. long and thin. It's the two angle property which I'm struggling to get my head around splitting in order to get symmetrical equal surface areas on the unit sphere. I also need to polar equations of their centres too!

Help would very much be appreciated.

Mark

Comment: Do you want these divisions to be congruent to each other or just have equal solid angle?

Comment: I want the divisions to have equal solid angle and their surface areas subtended to be physically identical to each other, just moved to different areas of space in order to fill up the unit sphere. Imagine dividing the surface of a sphere into 3 equal parts. I want the equations for these parts, I.e their boundaries in the 2 angles given an arbitrary start reference. Also want the locations of their mid points. I think this means congruent, but I'm not sure!

Comment: What you ask is possible only if you divide a sphere into 4, 6, 8, 12 or 20 parts. Those parts corresponding to the faces of a [platonic solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid).

Comment: For n=3 it seems to be possible if you split the sphere like a chocolate orange, i.e. only divide the longitude into 3. The three surfaces then fit on top of each other equally, and also each surface occupies one third of the total solid angle. The centre points of these surfaces also all lie on the xy plane, and if we join these three points we end up with a trigonal planar presentation.

Comment: However for n=4 if we do the same, I.e. split by longitude only, then we also end up with 4 segments of the sphere. Their solid angle also adds up correctly, however their centre points also create 4 points of the xy plane in a square. This was not the answer I was looking for. For n=4 I was requiring a tetrahedral solution. How do I vary $\theta$ and $\Phi$ to partition n=4 surface area into this format? Is there a general solution for maximising the average distance between midpoints of area segments created by equally splitting the solid angle? Similar to molecular structure.